# Post multiple html checkbox to asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms, http-post

I want to submit multiple html checkbox controls to asp.net I had done it in php and it is quite simple  but in asp.net is not working my asp.net code is like that

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="2" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="3" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="4" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="5" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="6" />
        <input type="text" name="text" />
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <%
        if (Request.Form["btn"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write(Request.Form["text"]);
            Response.Write(Request.Form["checkbox"]);
        }
         %>
```

I render the checkboxes using `Response.Write` so I can't use server controls here.

Comment: set a breakpoint at `Request.Form` and check the keys... Maybe try `Request.Form["checkbox[]"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Request.Form["checkbox[]"] instead of Request.Form["checkbox"].